# social-share Non-static method should not be called statically in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to use [social-share](https://github.com/prodeveloper/social-share) plugin for Laravel.

In the doc, it is not marked how use in a controller (I start in Laravel).

I try this

```
public function share()
{
    $test = Share::load(URL::current(), 'Description de test')->twitter();
    return $test;
}
```

And in my method show()

```
return view('posts.postWork', [
        'share' => $this->share()
    ]);
```

And I have an error :

`Non-static method Chencha\Share\Share::load() should not be called statically`

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `use Chencha\Share\Share` to `use Share;` on the top of your page.

The `Share` class in the example is the Facade `Chencha\Share\ShareFacade` which should be resolved by laravel loader when you register `ShareServiceProvider`.

**EDIT**:
Just in case, the registration of the service is standard for laravel apps and is not covered in the readme. In order to use the plugin you need to add `Chencha\Share\ShareServiceProvider` to `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the alias in the app config file.

```
'Share' => Chencha\Share\ShareFacade::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

error in this line

```
$test = Share::load(URL::current(), 'Description de test')->twitter();
```

replace to this

```
$test = Share::load(url('/'), 'Description de test')->twitter();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can always call it non-statically

```
 return $shareComponent = (new \Jorenvh\Share\Share)->page(
'https://www.test.com',
'Your share text comes here'
)
->facebook()
->twitter()
->linkedin();
```